# Can a number which is part of EditText id be incremented using Loops to create a shorter code in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, kotlin, while-loop

I'm new to programming. I am aware of Kotlin's **While Loops** and **For Loops** but I am not knowledgeable enough to manipulate strings. I wonder if my code below could be shorten using **Loops**. Thanks.

This consists of 3 **b** blocks with 3 **p** parts each. My code need to check if the **TextView** is empty or else it will crash. That's why I'm checking for each individual **EditText** to check if it's blank.

I thought of separating the number part of **EditText id** and increment it before concantenating it to the **original id** but I cannot seem to do it.

Would it be possible to use **for loops** to replace the number in **b1p1** and then convert it back to **TextView**?

```
if (b1p1.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    if (b2p1.text.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (b3p1.text.isNotEmpty()) {

            var palm1 = b1p1.text.toString().toInt() + b2p1.text.toString().toInt() + b3p1.text.toString().toInt()
            total1.text = palm1.toString()

        } else
            Toast.makeText(
            activity,"b3p1 is blank",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else
        Toast.makeText(
        activity,"b2p1 is blank",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} else
    Toast.makeText(
    activity,"b1p1 is blank",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

if (b1p2.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    if (b2p2.text.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (b3p2.text.isNotEmpty()) {

            var palm2 = b1p2.text.toString().toInt() + b2p2.text.toString().toInt() + b3p2.text.toString().toInt()
            total2.text = palm2.toString()
        } else
            Toast.makeText(
            activity,"b3p2 is blank",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else
        Toast.makeText(
        activity,"b2p2 is blank",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} else
    Toast.makeText(
    activity,"b1p2 is blank",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


if (b1p3.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    if (b2p3.text.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (b3p3.text.isNotEmpty()) {

            var palm3 = b1p3.text.toString().toInt() + b2p3.text.toString().toInt() + b3p3.text.toString().toInt()
            total3.text = palm3.toString()

        } else
            activity,"b3p3 is blank",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else
    vToast.makeText(
        activity,"b2p3 is blank",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
} else
    Toast.makeText(
    activity,"b1p3 is blank",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code mentioned in the question, you do not require loops to iterate or find EditText views by manually iteration through IDs. Instead you can do something like this:

```
    private fun viewIteration(){
        val editTextList = ArrayList<EditText> ()
        b1p1.tag = "b1p1"
        editTextList.add(b1p1)
        b2p1.tag = "b2p1"
        editTextList.add(b2p1)
        b3p1.tag = "b2p1"
        editTextList.add(b3p1)

        if(b1p1.text.isNotEmpty() && b2p1.text.isNotEmpty() && b3p1.text.isNotEmpty()){
            // Your code goes here
        } else{
            for(editText in editTextList){
                if(editText.text.isNotEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"${editText.tag} is blank",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you are making an ArrayList of views and tagging them. A for loop is required when your main condition is not met. i.e. any of the three EditText views do not have text. In this case the code will loop through your views and make Toast messages for the EditText views that do not contain text.

This is one way to shorten your code, if you however still want to manually iterate through your view identifiers, use this method:

```
    private fun getEditTextById(id: String) : EditText{
        return findViewById<EditText>(resources.getIdentifier("b${id}p1","id",packageName))
    }
```

This method takes an id as a String and uses it to construct your identifier name, in this case "b{n}p1", it'll find the resource and return it as EditText view.